# Rails 4 throws image has errors when i use send_data with image magick image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

I have an issue when I send an image with `send_data` method in Rails.
I have a controller with a helper method that sends the image data to an image tag

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

 helper_method :img


 def index

 end

 def img
   image.resize '1600x900'
   image.rotate '180'

   File.open(image.path, 'r') do |f|
     send_data f, filename: 'gift_front.jpg', :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline'
   end

 end
end
```

And the view is just this line:

```
<%= image_tag img, alt: 'Loading Image...', title: 'image' %>
```

But when the page is loaded in the browser I get this error:

> The image “http://localhost:3000/” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

I use rails 4.1.2 and ruby 2.2.2. The rails log doesn’t show any errors. I need to get a functionality where image data is sent to the browser, from an image out of the project, and this looks like the only solution, but I can't find a solution to this error.

Comment: Please check the terminal where you are executing `rails s` and look for an error message when you load the page.

Comment: The server log doesn't show any errors, just this  Processing by  **HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Sent data gift_front.jpg (2.3ms)
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (610.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 747ms (Views: 719.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)